# Как правильно расставить знаки пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация

Например, вы можете написать статьи на темы: Как приготовить отбивную, Как правильно сложить рубашку? Как зарегистрироваться в соцсети?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы исключил двоеточие, взял все названия названия в кавычки и по желанию поставил бы вопросительные знаки при каждом названии.